# Is it possible to specialize on a typedef and its underlying type separately?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, template-specialization

Simple example is size_t. Suppose:

```
typedef uint64_t size_t;
```

And I want to specialize differently on uint64_t and size_t:

```
template <class T>
struct MyType {};

template <>
struct MyType<uint64_t>{
    void operation()() { cout << "uint64_t" << endl; }
};

template <>
struct MyType<size_t>{
    void operation()() { cout << "size_t" << endl; }
}

MyType<1ULL>()();
MyType<static_cast<size_t>(1ULL)>()();
```

Is this even possible? Is there a trick to get the same net effect?

Comment: You can try `enum class my_size_t : size_t { }`.

Comment: yea, but that kind assumes the direct use of my_size_t by the user. trying to avoid that.

Comment: I don't think yo can do what you are trying. I'll let others prove me wrong by using clever tricks.

Comment: Thats what I'm thinking. Might be wishful of me.

Comment: This is not possible as all a typedef is is an alias, it does not introduce a new type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible.

The Standard (7.1.3, [dcl.typedef]) reads:

> A name declared with the `typedef` specifier becomes a *typedef-name*. Within the scope of its declaration, a *typedef-name* is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier in the way described in Clause 8. **A *typedef-name* is thus a synonym for another type**. **A *typedef-name* does not introduce a new type** the way a class declaration (9.1) or enum declaration does.

Comment: This was my assumption, but an example where the compiler handles this differently somehow is printf. size_t, ptrdiff_t and other types can map directly to uint64_t yet are detected, handled, and validated differently. That is probably not based on the definition of a type though.

Comment: @Jaime, please give a concrete example. There should be nothing special in `printf()` in this respect.

Comment: Sure, on Windows 64bit, with size_t you can use %tu or %Iu (capital i) for printf, but uint64_t usually wants %llu or %I64u. These map to the same type via a typedef. Not template related, but the compiler can presumably detect the difference and validate separately. So was hoping something similar could be done with type definitions. Your post seems to imply not :(

Comment: If `size_t` and `uint64_t` are the same type, you can use these flags interchangeably, and compiler won't be able to detect the difference. What compiler can do is to detect `sizeof(size_t)` and then interpret these flags differently.

Comment: On some compilers that is true. On others I think it will look at the initial type and validate when format warnings are turned on. But I agree, at run-time all it has is size, so they should work interchangeably, just a question if the compile time validator is smart enough.

Comment: @Jaime MSVC just warns that "[the sizes of types '::size_t' and 'unsigned __int64' might differ on other platforms](https://godbolt.org/g/x5FWVS)". It still treats both types as the same when compiling.